# Trying to subtract two dates to find number of days inbetween

Tags: python, datetime, zapier

Within Zapier, I have two dates and am trying to find the number of days between them in a Code Step. I run a Formatter Step on each date to output a datetime object in YYYY-MM-DD then run the following code below:

```
submit = input['submit_date']
event = input['event_date']
delta = event-submit
numdays = delta.days

return {'numdays': numdays}
```

The error I get suggests the two dates that i'm importing are strings, not datetimes.

Here is the error:

`Your code had an error! Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/tmp7xyg3Z/usercode.py", line 10, in the_function delta = event-submit TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'`

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong or a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Looks like `submit` and `event` are strings - you want them as `datetime` to do math on them.

Answer (score 3):

The formatter steps aren't included, but in general you are wanting time or datetime objects (`import time`  or `import datetime`)

You should probably be looking at something like `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)` from the datetime option to take your text string and convert it to a date/time object.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 methods `get_days(start_date, end_date)` and `increment_da_day(str_date)`

invoke `get_days()` it returns you a list of days(format is yyyymmdd), you can provide your start date and end date and print the `get_days(start_date, end_date) - 1`

For example:

import datetime

```
def get_days(start_date, end_date):
    """returns a list of days"""
    all_days = []
    starts = start_date
    all_days.append(starts)

    while int(starts) < int(end_date):
        starts = increment_a_day(starts)
        all_days.append(starts)
    return all_days

def increment_a_day(str_date):
    """increments a day for given date string in format yyyymmdd"""
    year = int(str_date[:4])
    month = int(str_date[4:6])
    day = int(str_date[-2:])

    now = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return (now + delta).strftime('%Y%m%d') #yyyymmdd
```

You only need to do following:

```
days = get_days("20160601", "20160602")

delta =  len(days) - 1
print delta
```

Answer (score 0):

if they are strings the you can either pass input or take the input right there, the following code will return the days

```
def h():
    from datetime import datetime
    date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"
    a = datetime.strptime(input('Enter first date in MM/DD/YY format '), date_format)
    b = datetime.strptime(input('Enter second date in MM/DD/YY format '), date_format)
    delta = b - a
    print (delta.days)
    return int(delta.days)
```

or

```
a='8/18/2008'
b='9/26/2008'
def h(c,d):
    from datetime import datetime
    date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"
    a = datetime.strptime(c, date_format)
    b = datetime.strptime(d, date_format)
    delta = b - a
    print (delta.days)
    return int(delta.days)
```